# Simplify With For Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I am not very good with VBA and how it exactly how everything works but I am sure what I am doing can be condensed I am just not exactly sure how.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
Sub This()
If ComboBox5.Value = "Test" Then

If Range("R20").Value > 1 Then

Range("D37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[14]))+R[-17]C"

Range("E37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[13]))+R[-17]C"

Range("F37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[12]))+R[-17]C"

Range("G37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[11]))+R[-17]C"

Range("H37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[10]))+R[-17]C"

Range("I37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[9]))+R[-17]C"

Range("J37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[8]))+R[-17]C"

Range("K37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[7]))+R[-17]C"

Range("L37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[6]))+R[-17]C"

Range("M37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[5]))+R[-17]C"

Range("N37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[4]))+R[-17]C"

Range("O37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[3]))+R[-17]C"

Range("P37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[2]))+R[-17]C"
End If
End If
```

I recorded this Macro, and it works fine, but if I want to do this as well for `Range(R23)` it is kind of pain. So how would I go about condensing this code. I am sure the formula is not very clear so I want the new updated value of D37 to be:

```
D37 = (|(R20 - 1)|*D20) + D20
```

Comment: You wrote `for` loop in your title...

Comment: @findwindow I know I was hoping that somebody could help me with it...

Comment: `Range("D37:R37").FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C18))+R[-17]C"` that's it not loops.

Comment: @ScottCraner good catch. That's why I hate the R1C1 notation :D

Comment: Just guessing: maybe `R[-17]` should be changed to `R20`, but the question is vague.

Comment: @DavidZemens It has always seemed backwards to me.  Since we have to add `$` to make it absolute in the worksheet and nothing for relative the same should be for R1C1, but alas microsoft in their infinite wisodm...

Comment: @BrakNicku I would agree that it might need to be changed to that, but as the question does not state or even hint at that the formula will be copied to other rows, I hesitate to change it.

Comment: @ScottCraner It does hint here: _but if I want to do this as well for Range(R23)_

Comment: @BrakNicku you are probably correct.  but there should be enough information here now for the OP to figure it out.  Feel free to suggest your finished formula that shows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly something like this, though I try not to use R1C1 notation because it is so difficult to read, so I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for.

```
Sub This()
If ComboBox5.Value = "Test" Then

Dim rng as Range, cl as Range, i as Long

If Range("R20").Value > 1 Then
    Set rng = Range("D37:P37")
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C18))+R[-17]C"
End If

If Range("R23").Value > 1 Then
    '## NOTE: You may need to modify if the Column changes
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C18))+R[-17]C"
Next
End Sub
```

Explanation of why I use `C18` in the formula:

You're original code is using R1C1 notation with *relative* reference. As you traverse your range of cells (moving from left-to-right) your formula is decrementing the column position, e.g.:

```
Range("D37").FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[14]))+R[-17]C"  '## C[14]
Range("E37").FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[13]))+R[-17]C"  '## C[13]
```

So this means that even though you're changing the offset value in the brackets, you're still refering to the same column, which can be identified in absolute terms using R1C1 notation `C18`

Comment: can you explain why you use C18 in the formula?

Comment: @AdamWarner see revised answer which includes explanation.

Comment: awesome explanation. Some wacky syntax comes out of VBA sometimes

Comment: If you switch your reference style to A1 notation, it's a lot easier to read & manipulate, at least in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are placing nearly the same formula in every column in the same row. So, as your title suggests, a for-loop might be appropriate. For instance,

```
 For j = 4 to 100 'or whatever the last column number you want to be
    cells(37, j).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-17]C*(1-R[-17]C[" & 18 - j & "]))+R[-17]C"
 next j
```

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I made an edit to at least be able to reproduce the end result of OP's code. Good catch.